# How to update widget when new style is applied

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I'm making an extension with a list containing a checkbox with a text item (St.label) that change style when toggled.

I'm listening to the toggle event, and as the item is toggled, I set a new style for my text using set_style_class_name() on a my Stlabel. But the style of the object don't change. The only solution that I have found is to destroy and remake all the item of the list and set a different class in the init of the object.

How could I just update the item that have been checked ?

Here the item that I'm using, I put a listener on the checkbox that trigger the toggle() function, in this function I'm updating the class, which should remove the 'text-checked' class and so the text should't have 'text-decoration:line-through' property.

```
const PopupMenu = imports.ui.popupMenu;
const Lang = imports.lang;
const { Atk, Clutter, St, GObject } = imports.gi;
const ExtensionUtils = imports.misc.extensionUtils;
const Me = ExtensionUtils.getCurrentExtension();
const CheckboxLib = Me.imports.src.checkbox;

var PopupCheckBoxMenuItem = GObject.registerClass({
    Signals: {
      'toggled': { param_types: [GObject.TYPE_BOOLEAN] },
      'deleted': { param_types: [GObject.TYPE_BOOLEAN] }
    },
}, class PopupCheckBoxMenuItem extends PopupMenu.PopupBaseMenuItem {
    _init(text, active, params) {
        super._init(params);
        this.label = new St.Label({
          text: text,
          y_align:Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,
          x_expand: true,
          style_class: active ? "text-checked" : ""
        });
        this.tags = new St.Label({
          text: "API",
          y_align:Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,
          style_class: "tag-item"
        });
        this.icon = new St.Button({
          style_class: 'remove-task',
          can_focus: true,
        });

        this.icon.connect('clicked', Lang.bind(this,function(){
          this.emit('deleted', this._checkbox.state);
        }));

        this.icon.add_actor(new St.Icon({
          icon_name: 'window-close-symbolic',
          style_class: 'icon-remove-task'
        }));
        this._checkbox = new CheckboxLib.CheckBox(active);

        this._checkbox.connect('clicked', Lang.bind(this,function(){
          this.toggle();
                }));

        this.accessible_role = Atk.Role.CHECK_MENU_ITEM;
        this.checkAccessibleState();

        this._statusBin = new St.Bin({
            x_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.START,
            x_expand: false,
        });
        this.add_child(this._statusBin);

        this.label_actor = this.label;
        this.add_child(this.tags);
        this.add_child(this.label);

        this.add_child(this.icon);

        this._statusLabel = new St.Label({
            text: '',
            style_class: 'popup-status-menu-item',
        });
        this._statusBin.child = this._checkbox;
    }

    setStatus(text) {
        if (text != null) {
            this._statusLabel.text = text;
            this._statusBin.child = this._statusLabel;
            this.reactive = false;
            this.accessible_role = Atk.Role.MENU_ITEM;
        } else {
            this._statusBin.child = this._checkbox;
            this.reactive = true;
            this.accessible_role = Atk.Role.CHECK_MENU_ITEM;
        }
        this.checkAccessibleState();
    }

    activate(event) {
        super.activate(event);
    }

    toggle() {
        this._checkbox.toggle();
        this.emit('toggled', this._checkbox.state);
        //Updating class
        this.label.set_style_class_name("new_class");
        this.label.real_style_changed();
        this.checkAccessibleState();
    }

    get state() {
        return this._checkbox.state;
    }

    get delete_icon() {
        return this.icon;
    }

    setToggleState(state) {
        this._checkbox.state = state;
        this.checkAccessibleState();
    }

    checkAccessibleState() {
        switch (this.accessible_role) {
        case Atk.Role.CHECK_MENU_ITEM:
            if (this._checkbox.state)
                this.add_accessible_state(Atk.StateType.CHECKED);
            else
                this.remove_accessible_state(Atk.StateType.CHECKED);
            break;
        default:
            this.remove_accessible_state(Atk.StateType.CHECKED);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the property I changed in the css class.

For an unknown reason, style change doesn't seem to redraw when I set a class with only text-decoration property but if I add a change in the color, even if it is the same color it does work even without **St.Widget.style_changed()**.

So if I do **this.label.set_style_class_name("text-checked");** to change my class, the change doesn't work if my css class is as follow :

```
.text-checked
{
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
}
```

But this work :

```
.text-checked
{
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
    color: black;
}
```

Must be an issue with how the style change event work for Gjs component.

Issue open here : https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2811

Comment: That is interesting, good find! It would be great if you could open an issue for this in gnome-shell, this could be the cause of any number of strange bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct seems to be [`St.Widget.style_changed()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10~1.0_api/st.widget#method-style_changed). This seems to forcibly mark the style state as dirty and trigger a redraw (`St.Label` is a subclass, so just call `myLabel.style_changed()`).

The proper route is probably [`St.Widget.ensure_style()`](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/st10~1.0_api/st.widget#method-ensure_style), though.

I didn't look too deep, but the issue may be that widgets aren't being marked as having their style changed or maybe the change isn't being propagated to children or something.

Comment: I tried to use both of your method after setting the class, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you provide a larger code snippet? It's hard to see what might be going wrong without a bit more context.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get any notification you updated your snippet. What is `real_style_changed()`; I don't see that function defined anywhere. Are you getting any errors in your logs? My best recommendation here is to create a minimal reproducing example, because your snippet seems to be kind of complicated.

Comment: I found the reason of my problem, see my answer bellow. Thank you for your help.